# Google sheet API - PHP - Create a sheet

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-api-client

I have used google sheet API in php for create a new sheet , it is creating new sheet but i want to be it publicly editable but it is only accessed by particular gmail account only. which have owner,

So it is possible that to create a google sheet using API in php and allow it publicly editable?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### After [creating the spreadsheet with the Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create), you need to [update the permissions with the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

For this:

- Retrieve the spreadsheet id after creation
- Use this id as the `fileId` parameter for [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)
- Specify in the `Request body`

```
{
  "role": "writer",
  "type": "anyone"
}
```

Comment: i am using this API using google explore and i acheive what i want but when i use PHP curl and call this API i am getting this error

{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions", "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes." } ], "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes." } } 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show your code? Did you include the necessary scopes in it? And delete the old token file after updating the scopes?

Comment: You are right, i haven't given required scopes, It is working now, Thank you.

Comment: i am facing one more issue using this API, it is accessible by another google logged in user, but this sheet cannot be used by user which is not logged in google, when i try to access this sheet by incognito mode it asks me to logged in google account, is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

All write operations for the google sheets api require authorization

[image]

You need to use Oauth2 request consent of the user to use any write function even if the sheet is public.